# Login using SDK 3.1, $facebook->getUser() is zero?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

So I've setup the basic example code the SDK suggests.

I'm having such a problem, well many problems as I'm sure you all are too.

I've used both the session approach with SDK 2.12, my current problem is, even though I'm passing the `getLoginUrl` a `redirect_uri`, it ignores this and redirects it to my `base_domain +`

```
'{"session_key":"badsdsadsdsdasdsd.0-1268121831","uid":"badsdsadsdsdasdsd","expires":0,"secret":"730aa9badsdsadsdsdasdsd","base_domain":"slumber-roo.co.uk","access_token":"badsdsadsdsdasdsdEZBZAZAvdRAZC6PwPeBZBYMZD","sig":"badsdsadsdsdasdsdd761385"}'
```

Obviously filled in with keyboard smash.

Now, my attempt with SDK 3.1 is weird. I have a valid `getUser`, but my colleague doesn't and gets stuck in the infinite loop.

I do understand the differences between `getSession` and `getUser` with SDK 2 and 3 respectively.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$user = null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($me);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_hometown',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/CharlesTestPage/225802194155435?sk=app_252946408094785'
            )
    );
    exit('<script> top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'"; </script>');
}

function d($d){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

**Oh, in addition, I'm running this app solely inside a tab.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the application in sandbox mode? Have you added your collegue as an ADMIN || DEVELOPER || TESTER in the app config?

I just got that this morning, my project manager was in an infinite loop, added her as tester in the app but she hadn't accepted the pending invite and was looping.